# Why don't my controls update when I change them in another method?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
public partial class Person : Window
{
    private static TabControl tabControl;
    public Person()
    {
              InitializeComponent();
              tabControl = new TabControl();
              grid.Children.Add(tabControl);
    }

    public void someMethod(String name){
        TabItem newTab = new TabItem();
        newTab.Header = name;
        tabControl.Items.Add(newTab);
    }
}

public class Update{
    public void createGUI(String name){
        Person newPerson = new Person();
        newPerson.someMethod(name);
    }
}
```

The method someMethod is called  **in another class** at some point after creating the class. It is called after InitializeComponent and everything in the constructor. However, the tab control still has no tabs even after someMethod finished.

Edit: To clarify, the Update method is only called once through the lifetime of the application. I only want one instance of Person.

Comment: Can you provide the minimum code that would show the calling class as well?

Comment: There is no reason why `tabControl` should be a static field. `private TabControl tabControl;` should be ok, or probably better `private readonly TabControl tabControl;`.

Comment: Does you calling class have a reference to the correct object?

Comment: This is the minimum code and tabControl is static because it is reference by    a static method in the same class.

Comment: That is poor design. It won't work as you expect when you create a second instance of your Person class. Please take the time to read up on the basics of OOP and C#.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void createGUI(String name){
    Person newPerson = new Person();
    newPerson.someMethod(name);
}
```

There, you are creating a *new Person object* which is completely unrelated to the one that is being displayed to you. That new object is actually never displayed anywhere, so whatever you change about it, won’t be visible to you.

Instead, you need to change the Person object that is actually around and displayed.

Alternatively, you could also show the new object by using `newPerson.Show()` but that will open a new window and not change the existing one.

Comment: there is only one instance though. newPerson is the only instance of the object(and i only want one instance). The next time i create a newPerson is when i exit the application and reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

The simple reason is that you create a new instance of the Person class every time you update, so the change in one instance cannot be reflected in another instance.

Comment: static members of class are independent of instance members.

Comment: It does not matter because the static field is re-initialized every time the constructor is called ( tabControl = new TabControl();)